# Are there ways to determine a star's spectral type without the spectrum itself?

Tags: star, exoplanet, stellar-evolution, stellar-astrophysics, classification

Because of the lack of available data online, I am trying to find other ways to determine an exoplanet's host star's spectral type.

Comment: Are you asking about how to observe a specific star and classify it without the use of a spectrograph, or how to *look up* the spectral type of a specific star, or something else?

Comment: Ok so I have radial velocity measurements for specific stars, however, I dont have the stellar spectrum for that star. I do want to classify that star.

Answer (score 3):

The color index of the star can give you that information. I can look it up for you if I know which exoplanet you're interested in, or you can find it in the NASA Exoplanet Database [here](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/index.html).

Comment: I know that, I have the host star, however without using that website How Can I classify it?

Comment: I’m confused by what you’re trying to do here. In your original question you said “because of the lack of available data online”, but now this answer is pointing you to where the answer could be found online and you seem not to want to use that information.  So it would be helpful if you would clarify your goal, and what sort of information or data is admissible to achieve that. Is it that you want to know *in general* how to find spectral types, not just for one specific star?